# Echo Warning or Confirmation on Condition

Tags: php

What I expect on execution:

The function `Email()` will be called each time the page loads. If `$Valid` exists `Email()` should return either *true* or *false*. If `$Valid` does not exist `Email()` checks the `Postback()` (example: has the page been submitted and we're seeing it for the second time?) and if *true* `Validate()`s the form fields and either sets `$Valid=1` (for *true*) and sends `mail()` or sets `$Valid=0` (for *false*).

Now `$Valid` exists `Email()` should just return a *true* or *false* when called for the second time, say for example by a function to echo a warning or confirmation message if `mail()` successfully sent or not.

What's happening?

`$Valid` isn't set it seems when `Email()` is initially called so when we call `Email()` a second time the `isset($Valid)` `if` clause always returns *false*.

I really hope you can help, I appreciate any answers and thank you all!

BTW: I know we could "`try`" and "`catch`" `mail()` too but I've cut down the complexity of the code as much as I can so it's easier to digest!

Here's the code I need help with:

```
function Validate(){
    if(!empty($_POST["From"])&&!empty($_POST["Body"])){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    };
};
function Postback(){
    if(isset($_POST["Return"])){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    };
};
function Email(){
    if(isset($Valid)){
        if($Valid!=0){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        };
    }else{
        if(Postback()){
            if(Validate()){
                $Valid=1;
            }else{
                $Valid=0;
            };
        };
    };
};
Email();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare `$Valid` as static if you want its value to be preserved across function calls, for example:

```
function Email() {
    static $Valid = null;
    if ($Valid !== null) {
        if($Valid!=0){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        };
    } else {
        //etc.
    }
}
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php:

Note that the value will not be preserved across HTTP requests, if you need that you should look at storing the data in a Session.

Answer (score 0):

You need to somehow preserve $Valid across page loads, e.g. in a session variable.